# Laravel Paypal error when adding PayPal::details() in transaction

Tags: laravel-5, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

First time doing `paypal` integration in `laravel`. I'm trying to add details such as subtotal of items and totaltax, I have this controller.

```
$payer = PayPal::Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item1 = PayPal::item();
item1->setName('Item1 name')
->setDescription('item1 description')
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice(35);

$item2 = PayPal::item();
$item2->setName('Item2 name')
->setDescription('item2 description')
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice(300);

$itemList = PayPal::itemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1,$item2));

$details = PayPal::Details();
$details->setShipping(1);
$details->setTax(10);      
$details->setSubtotal(17.5);

$amount = PayPal::Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal(335)
->setDetails($details);

$transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
$transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');


$redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('paypal_Controller\paypalctr@getDone'));
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('paypal_Controller\paypalctr@getCancel'));


$payment = PayPal::Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
$redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
```

I got this error:

> PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 177:
>      Got Http response code 400 when accessing    https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

But when I remove `->setDetails($details)`, it works but no subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Paypal only accepts correct computation.
If you want to add totaltax u need to add ->setTax() per item.

```
$item1 = PayPal::item();
$item1->setName('Item1 Name')
->setDescription('Item1 Description')
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity('2')
->setTax(2.0)
->setPrice('350');

 $item2 = PayPal::item();
 $item2->setName('Item2 Name')
 ->setDescription('Item2 Description')
 ->setCurrency('USD')
 ->setQuantity('1')
 ->setTax(0)
 ->setPrice('300');
```

Then computation must be correct.item1 tax =(2.0 * 2) + item2 tax = 0 totaltax = 4.0 item1 price = (350 * 2) + item2 price = 300 subtotal = 1000.

```
$details = PayPal::details();
$details->setShipping('0');
$details->setTax(4.0);      
$details->setSubtotal('1000');
```

shipping + totaltax + subtotal = 1004.0

```
$amount = PayPal::Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal(1004.0);
$amount->setDetails($details);
```

Hope it will help someone. :)